# Solve a nonlinear equation using ODE45 function in matlab for different values of initial conditions

Tags: matlab, ode45, nonlinear-equation

I have written a script to compute and solve a simple inverted pendalum system.Now suppose that I want to solve the nonlinear dynamic equation of the system with ODE45 function with different values of initial conditions.How could I use a for loop to solve for state vector of X for different values of initial conditions?I wrote a for loop to do that but I could not get the answer I wanted.Help me please.Here are my function and mfile as follows:

```
function xDot = of(x,g,L,u)

xDot = zeros(2,1);

xDot(1) = x(2);
xDot(2) = ((g./L)*sin(x(1)))+u;

end
```

And this is my main code:

```
    clc;
clear;close all;

    %% Solve The Nonlinear Equation

L = 1;
g = 9.81;

h = 0.25;
t = [0:h:5];
A = [0 1;(g/L) 0];
B =[0 1]';
Ics = [pi,0;pi/2 0;pi/5 0;0.001 0;pi 0.5;pi/2 0.5;pi/5 0.5;0.001 0.5];
[Poles,~] = eig(A);     %Poles Of Closed LOop System
R = 0.01;
Q = eye(2);
K = lqr(A,B,Q,R);

u = @(x)-K*(x);


for i=1:size(Ics,1)
    [~,X] = ode45(@(t,x)of(x,g,L,u(x)),t,Ics(i,:));

end
```

Also note that I want the first column of X vector which is the angular displacements of the pendulum in each iteration because the second column of X vector in ODE45 is always the Derivative of the main state vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the integration outputs for the different initial conditions in a 3D array.

The number of rows of `Xout` will equal the number of time steps at which you want to evaluate your solution, so `numel(t)`. The number of columns is the number of states, and then the third dimension will be the number of initial conditions you want to test.

```
Xout = zeros(numel(t), size(Ics, 2), size(Ics, 1)); % initialize the 3D array 
for k = 1:size(Ics, 1)
    [~, Xout(:, :, k)] = ode45(@(t, x)of(x, g, L, u(x)), t, Ics(k, :));
end
```

Comment: That's right.But is there any other way to do this?.Because I want to and I need to have a matrix of state vector which I could easily plot these states versus time vector